# show all rows in dataframe with 1) none == 1 and at least one other column == 1

Tags: r

I would like to subset all rows in the df that have "none == 1" AND either a == 1 or b == 1. Since I have like 50 columns it takes too long to write ... & (a==1 | b == 1 | c== 1 etc...)
How can I easily check if all other columns are == 1? I tried dplyr filter but no success.

```
df <- data.frame(none = c(1,0,1,0,1,1), 
                 a = c(0,1,0,0,0,1), 
                 b = c(0,0,0,0,1,0))

mydesiredoutput <- data.frame(none = c(1,1), 
                 a = c(0,1), 
                 b = c(1,0) ) #  basically row 5 and 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

```
df[df$none == 1 & rowSums(df) == 2,]

#  none a b
#5    1 0 1
#6    1 1 0
```

**NOTE** You can change the rowsum from `==` to `>=` If needed

Comment: I think `rowSums(df) > 1` . Also `df[df$none == 1 & rowSums(df[-1] == 1) > 0, ]`

Comment: @RonakShah Yea, I added a note since OP first mention a OR b and then a AND b

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` way with your mentioned `filter` function:

```
df %>% 
  filter(none == 1) %>%
  filter_at(vars(-none), any_vars(. == 1)) 

#   none a b
#1    1 0 1
#2    1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution with `across()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(none == 1 & rowSums(across(-none, ~ . == 1)) > 0)

#   none a b
# 1    1 0 1
# 2    1 1 0
```

which supersedes the use of scoped verbs and `any_vars()` in @tamtam's answer since `dplyr 1.0.0`.